# How to pass dropdown value with "other" option through php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropdown

[enter image description here](https://ibb.co/61tLX6v)I want to pass the option value to another page. For this purpose I have some options. Besides there is an "other" option where an input field is hidden. My javascript code works i.e; selection of "others" appear the desired text input. But while passing the value (submitting) the "other" option (input field) pass the value but not the regular option.

```js
function CheckColors(val) {
  var element = document.getElementById('color_change');
  if (val == 'pick a color' || val == 'others')
    element.style.display = 'block';
  else
    element.style.display = 'none';

}
```

```html
<form action="action_dropdown.php" method="post">
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'>
    <option>pick a color</option>
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="color" id="color_change" style='display:none;' />
  <input value="calculation" type="submit">
</form>
```

```
$myVariable = $_POST["color"];

echo $myVariable;
```

I expect my output would be red/ blue/ (while selecting any of them).
Again I want my output would be yellow (when I choose "ohters" and input "yellow".)

Being a novice I Hope your cordial cooperation.

Comment: You have two items with name="color' In PHP you need to name them `color[]` and you will receive an array. Or just rename the second color field to "others"

Comment: <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> <input type="text" name="col_other" id="color_change" 
    style='display:none;'/>   Output: "Yellowothers" (As I fill input with yellow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename your input element by any other as below:

```
<form action="action_dropdown.php" method="post">
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'>
    <option>pick a color</option>
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="othercolor" id="color_change" style='display:none;' />
  <input value="calculation" type="submit">
</form>
```

And when your form is submitted, you need to check whether `othercolor` is set or not. Thus you can get color value like below:

```
$selectedColor = ($_POST['color'] == "others" ) ?  $_POST['othercolor']: $_POST['color'];
```

Thus, you will be able to access both select and input values. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Rohit Mittal. It can pass the option value but when I want to pass 'yellow' selecting 'others' it passes like 'yellowothers'. I cannot overcome that.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this so I can check better?

Comment: updated my answer accordingly. Basically, you need to use only one value either `othercolor` or `color`. Check if it helps you!!

Comment: Great, happy it helped you. Hope you will accept my answer :)